# Mail being sent to local domain instead of remote domain

Tags: linux, email, qmail, mta

I have a server which hosts mywebsite.com

If I try to send mail to info@mywebsite.com, the MTA is trying to send it to a local host (the mail is managed on a different server). How can I fix this?!

Its a linux server running qmail

Any more info needed please ask

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, the system has Plesk on it, needed to disable the mail service on the domain to stop it from sending to itself

Comment: You could also remove the domain from Plesk but that would probably in turn disable the www services.